# HTTP Status 404: The requested resource is not available/ Tomcat7

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven

I have been working on my java application for a couple of days.The project is a simple `Spring,Hibernate,jsf,mysql` integration which I run on Eclipse. The aim of the program is to add a Person(id, first name, last name, gender, age etc.) database on `MySQLWorkbench` and run it on server.I used Spring4, Hibernate4 and Eclipse Luna as tools.And I constructed the project as maven.
The database works well for now, I can add new rows when I just run the main class.But when it comes to run it on server, I fail.
I watched some tutorials on Youtube and see some effective ways to use Tomcat7.On my first try to run java application I applied the following steps:

1-I create a new server(Tomcatv7.0 Server) via right clicking Servers folder on Project Explorer.

2-I added my project to configure it on the server via right clicking on the server and choosing "Add and Remove"

3-Again, I right clicked on project Run As --> Run on Server.

By the way, I faced an output on the console:

```
    Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Example' did not find a matching property.
    Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.61
    Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server built:          Mar 27 2015 12:03:56 UTC
    Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server number:         7.0.61.0
    Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Name:               Mac OS X
    Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Version:            10.9.5
    Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Architecture:          x86_64
    Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
    Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_31-b13
    Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/fulden/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
    Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /Library/Tomcat
    Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/fulden/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
    Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Library/Tomcat
    Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/Users/fulden/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
    Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Library/Tomcat/endorsed
    Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
    Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
   INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/fulden/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
   Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
   INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8083"]
   Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
   INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8011"]
   Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
   INFO: Initialization processed in 446 ms
   Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
   INFO: Starting service Catalina
   Apr 22, 2015 8:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
   INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.61
   Apr 22, 2015 8:52:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
   INFO: The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
   Apr 22, 2015 8:52:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
   INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Apr 22, 2015 8:52:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
   INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
   INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
   INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Apr 22 20:52:16 EEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
   INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF//applicationContext.xml]
   WARN : org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
   INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1284 ms
Apr 22, 2015 8:52:17 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.10 ( 20150205-0906 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.10@14334) for context '/Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Example'
Apr 22, 2015 8:52:17 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Apr 22, 2015 8:52:18 PM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 5.0
Apr 22, 2015 8:52:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8083"]
Apr 22, 2015 8:52:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8011"]
Apr 22, 2015 8:52:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3900 ms
```

And, of course, there was "`HTTP Status 404: The requested resource is not available`" error when I typed `localhost:8083` to the browser.

Searching on similar questions here and other websites, I modified the server properties according to the given answers.For example, I created a new server; changed server location to "use tomcat installation(takes control of Tomcat installation)", and switched location on properties section via right clicking.

After running with this modifications, I have the same error on browser and the following output on console:

```
    Apr 22, 2015 9:08:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Example] has started
Apr 22, 2015 9:08:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Apr 22 20:52:16 EEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 22, 2015 9:08:48 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Example] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate$1] (value [com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate$1@1851267f]) and a value of type [com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate] (value [com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate@706c30e5]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Apr 22, 2015 9:08:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
Apr 22, 2015 9:08:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Apr 22, 2015 9:08:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Apr 22 21:08:50 EEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF//applicationContext.xml]
WARN : org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
ERROR: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure - HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hibernate.data.Person
WARN : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF//applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4033)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1524)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Entity class not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(TypeSafeActivator.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(TypeSafeActivator.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(TypeSafeActivator.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:148)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hibernate.data.Person
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(TypeSafeActivator.java:184)
    ... 38 more
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF//applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4033)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1524)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Entity class not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(TypeSafeActivator.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(TypeSafeActivator.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(TypeSafeActivator.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:148)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hibernate.data.Person
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(TypeSafeActivator.java:184)
    ... 38 more
Apr 22, 2015 9:08:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF//applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4033)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1524)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Entity class not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(TypeSafeActivator.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(TypeSafeActivator.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(TypeSafeActivator.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:148)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hibernate.data.Person
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(TypeSafeActivator.java:184)
    ... 38 more

Apr 22, 2015 9:08:50 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.10 ( 20150205-0906 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.10@14334) for context '/Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Example'
Apr 22, 2015 9:08:50 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Apr 22, 2015 9:08:51 PM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 5.0
Apr 22, 2015 9:08:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Apr 22, 2015 9:08:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Example] startup failed due to previous errors
Apr 22, 2015 9:08:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Apr 22, 2015 9:08:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Example] is completed
```

My project is here: https://github.com/fsel/Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Eclipse-Integration

And the project structure is as follows:
[image]

I know I have explained my work like a dummy, but I am exhausted of working on this problem.Maybe, there is something wrong with my web.xml file or something about maven dependencies.But I tried different ways to edit them as well.And same error, again!

Can you please explain me, what I do wrong?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What page are you expecting to see? I see you have index.xhtml inside WEB-INF, it should be at the root of webapp. 404 means "there is no file to serve".

Comment: and you need to type localhost:8083//Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Example to get to your application (that's the web context name)

Comment: I expect to see a Person table filled with datas on the page.I will change the location of index.xhtml.Could you also please tell how I should run the project?Via first way or the second way above?

Comment: Run As --> Run on Server is fine

Comment: @JPMoresmau I type it like that way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it was not able to find entity class Person.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hibernate.data.Person

Also, 
change
from : http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/
to : http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ 
in hibernate configuration file.

One more problem I noticed ,

you are using

class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
as well as

class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"

one class is from  **hibernate3** and one from **hibernate4**.
This can be reason for your problems.Stick to one version of spring orm.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I modified hibernate configuration file.But I couldn't figure out how to solve the entity class error.Should I move the Person class somewhere else?

Comment: try changing ,     <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.service"></context:component-scan> to     <context:component-scan base-package="com.*"></context:component-scan>